# Java Regex tab space

Tags: java, regex

I am new to Regex, so this is pretty much a basic question.
I tried to identify tab space and replace it by any letter, say R. But, the code does not seem to work. I am able to get the correct output for space characters though.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abs abd   abs   abd";
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\t","R"));    
}
```

The output comes out to be:
abs abd   abs   abd

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Those aren't tabs, they're spaces.

Comment: You probably typed that in an IDE. My IDE too, when I press tab, adds a certain number of spaces instead of actual tabs. Thus, you get that output.

Comment: You can use `\\s` to match all whitespace including tabs. Not sure it answers the question though...

Comment: @Andy Turner and Hackerdarshi, thanks for identifying the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Java API for regular expressions says that `\\s` will equal whitespace therefore, the regex `\\s\\s` should match for two spaces and so forth.

I don't know if it will help but try something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abs abd   abs   abd";
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\s","R")); 
    }
```

This will replace each space with a R if this is what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\s\\s\\s"," ")); this will work for tabs. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\s+` to match 1 or more whitespace characters. This could be 1 tab or multiple spaces, which are often used in place of tabs by most IDEs:

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\s+","R"));
```